# Surprising case where using `any` reports more errors than using `unknown`

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```js
type AnyObject = {
  [field: string]: unknown
}

interface SomeObject {
  someField: number
}

function isSomeObject(v: unknown): v is SomeObject {
  return true // unimportant
}

const f = (object: AnyObject) => {
  object.wrongField
  if (isSomeObject(object)) {
    object.wrongField
  }
}
```

([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiA8gIwFYQMbCgXigbwFgAoKKAbQDMBLCAGwBMAuKAZ2ACdq4BzAXRYBXOAGs4AewDucEgF8SJbsAgdKAQwzQAyuIC2EFOiwESZVnogAxWoxZxBu5CrkLilYVmri4Uaqx36hpjAABQAbkKiEtIAlCxhvqxQAQZowSakUBwQwIIcPpyC0AD0xVDC1Lpg4hzAanDALsQkGN7sUJS4UCHiaVgs8Eh9wDG4AHwZZL1GwAB0khzePNb0DKa+nSF+KUFYPcMxo0SZU8Pzi7wrjOvyxLJAA))

Neither access to `object.wrongField` reports an error, which is I guess sound behavior as the `AnyObject` type says that all properties are present.

Now if you change the `unknown` in `AnyObject` to `any`, the second access to `object.wrongField` suddenly reports an error, even though the first one didn’t. The type guard completely replaced the type, instead of intersecting it with the existing type.

This is pretty surprising, what is going on here? Usually, it is going from `any` to `unknown` that reports more errors, not the other way around. Note also that changing `SomeObject` to a type (instead of an interface) makes both `any` and `unknown` behave in the same way (with the second access to `object.wrongField` reporting an error).

Comment: This is *multiple* interacting features. ① A type guard that wants to narrow a value of type `A` to type `B` will only result in `B` if `B extends A`. Otherwise it results in the intersection `A & B`. ② `SomeObject` doesn't have an apparent `wrongField` property, but `SomeObject & AnyObject` does. ③ `{[k: string]: any}` is a supertype of any object type but `{[k: string]: unknown}` is not, see [docs](//devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/#k-string-unknown-is-no-longer-a-wildcard-assignment-target).

Comment: ④ Types are granted implicit index signatures but interfaces are not, see [ms/TS#15300](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300). ⊛ All of that put together yields the behavior you're seeing, but ugh, that's a lot to explain. I wish you could pare this down to a single topic (without, say, the "note also that changing `SomeObject` to a type..." part) so that my answer, if I post it, will be sub-book-length. So, uh, does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! Actually I would be most interested in why types and interfaces behave differently when it comes to index signatures. I understand the first three points (although I had forgotten the third one), but it's the first time I hear about this difference between types and interfaces.

Comment: So then maybe you could [edit] the question to be explicit about which thing you want answered?  There are so many moving pieces here that it would be nice if we could focus. If you're just asking "why do types and interfaces behave differently when it comes to index signatures", then you should probably replace your question with a simpler example [like this](https://tsplay.dev/N73kBN) and ask about that only.  But note that the canonical answer to that question is at [ms/TS#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) although I could elaborate on it. Would that work for you?